# Access a UIViewCotroller in AppDelegate in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I want to access a `UIViewcontroller` in AppDelegate. The hierarchy is shown here:[image]

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    let navController = self.window!.rootViewController as! UINavigationController
    let tabController = navController.topViewController as! UITabBarController

    var postController =  tabController.topViewController as! UITableViewController  
    // It is incorrect. has no member of topViewController

    return true
}
```

Comment: it's AppDelegate not AppDeligate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried something like:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    let navController = self.window!.rootViewController as! UINavigationController
    let tabController = navController.topViewController as! UITabBarController
    var postController =  tabController.viewControllers[0]
    // It is incorrect. has no member of topViewController
    return true
}
```

Tab bar controller manages a list of ViewControllers. In this case you want the first one in the list. Note the syntax might be a bit wrong as I don't have much swift experience!

```
var postController =  tabController.viewControllers[0]
```

That is the part I cahanged.

Answer (score 1):

```
if var topController = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController {
    while let presentedViewController = topController.presentedViewController {
        topController = presentedViewController
    }

    // topController should now be your topmost view controller
}
```

Comment: Thanks. If I want to access profile (it is shown in the picture). it is accessed from the detail page. how can I do this one?

Comment: I don't understand..!!

Comment: profile is one of the view controllers. It is shown in the picture.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you shouldn't have to access you controller from AppDelegate, it's a mistake in your app's architecture.
AppDelegate should only be used for app's lifecycle (launch/activation/deactivation/push notifications/...)
Why would you like to access your viewController here ?

Comment: I wanted to set delegate for one of the viewControllers.

Comment: You shouldn't set AppDelegate as delegate from a controller. Is there a reason why you choose AppDelegate to be the delegate or could it be another Object.
In your app's architecture, you should think about single responsability. Each object as one responsability (and only one !)
Your controller as the responsability to control your view's display/interactions but the business code should be in a manager (or anything else).
The AppDelegate's responsability is the app's lifecycle (and shouldn't take another)

Comment: Your right. I don't want necessarily put it in Appdelegate. It was a choice. I want to set a UIviewControllers delegate property to another UIviewController.

Answer (score 0):

you already did your forwarding with the storyboard,
all you have to do is:

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ application: UIApplication) {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let navigationController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "navigationController") // here you should insert your identifier (storyboard -> navigationcontroller -> Identity -> Storyboard ID) 

    window!.rootViewController = navigationController
    window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use storyboard identifier to access the view controller

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "storyboardIdentifier")
```

Comment: No, this creates a new instance. He wants to find the existing instance.